# unlinking a file in linux

Tags: linux, debian-jessie

I am new to Linux and trying to understand some things. In my docker image I see that the error.log is linked to stdout.

`ln -sfT /dev/stderr "/var/log/apache2/error.log"`

What is the command to unlink this so the error.log is written again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`unlink` and then `touch` the file.

```
$ unlink /var/log/apache2/error.log && touch /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

Then test the procedure by writing to the log:

```
$ echo "Test Line" >> /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

If `apache` for some reason is still not writing to the file, try reloading the service,

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can just delete the link:

```
rm /var/log/apache2/error.log
```

[EDIT]
While `rm` will work, the unlink command [seems to have a higher recommendation](http://osxdaily.com/2016/05/25/how-delete-symbolic-link-symlink/).

```
cd /var/log/apache2
unlink error.log
```

Comment: I tried unlink /var/log/apache2/error.log. That didn't help.

Comment: that's exactly what I did. The file was gone but errors kept going to stdout. No new file was created

Comment: try creating an empty file: "touch /var/log/apache2/error.log". If this doesn't work then there might be something unexpected in the application itself.